# How to create revolving current year calendar in Sharepoint online calendar app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to create a view for the current fiscal year that will update depending on the year we are in.

Our fiscal year goes from October 1 one year to September 31st in the next year.

I am trying to create a list view in the calendar app to be able to see this period.

I know I need to use the [Today] function somehow, but I do not know how to use this to define a different calendar year and then to only show this fiscal year's info in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two calculate column as below:

Start Year = DATE(YEAR([Created]),10,1)

End Year = DATE(YEAR([Created])+1,9,31)

Then, create a View with the  Filter as below:

Start Year is Less Than or Equal to [TODAY]  AND End Year is Greater Than Equal To [TODAY]

Comment: The view this created is only showing me the calendar year from January 1- December 31st. Columns work great and show correct year I think the issue is more with the view settings because Start year (Fiscal Year = FY) is actually last year and the end year is the current year.  Then FY 18 is October 1, 2017 - September 30, 2018.  The current suggested view both use this year.